# How does Jquery's .click() work?

Tags: jquery, click

I'm trying to simulate a user clicking an element by using:

```
      el = document.getElementById('#inputToClick');
      oEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      oEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, window, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
      el.dispatchEvent(oEvent);
```

This works for another site where jQuery's $el.click() does not, but I've found a site where jQuery's click works but the above does not.  I was hoping some one could point me to the relevant parts of the jQuery source.

Comment: Why don't you just invoke the onclick handler yourself? Creating a test framework?

Comment: The answer for your question literally in jquery sources

Comment: Yeah, check the source code if you want to know exactly how it works.

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for [jQuery(el).trigger('click');](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)?  `jQuery(el).click()` captures the click event, and it looks like you are trying to trigger a click event.

Comment: [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L969) and [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L198)

Comment: @eicto yep, just found: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.click  was struggling to find that, searching for "click" doesn't help :)

Comment: @cale_b .click() without arguments calls trigger, and thank you for the code for that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah, I'd done that but unfortunately I'm running it in phantomjs and I think this page has brutalised it's js so much that it returns true when the click doesn't actually work and returns false when it does!

Comment: I think this is the line that's doing the business: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8-stable/src/event.js#L347 which would be theElement.click(); but I'm not 100% sure. Followed it from: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8-stable/src/event.js#L1019 and https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8-stable/src/event.js#L211

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're realy looking for the source of the click function of jQuery 1.7.2:

```
function (data, fn) {
    if (fn == null) {
        fn = data;
        data = null;
    }

    return arguments.length > 0 ? this.on(name, null, data, fn) : this.trigger(name);
}
```

source:
[Jquery.Click Function](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.click)

And if you just wanted to know how to click on something...

```
$('#inputToClick').click();
```

Comment: It's nice, but you should never rely on source specifics. It could change in different versions. Instead rely only on what's specified in the API documentation. As such, there should very rarely be a need to look at the jQuery source and I think that site is over-promoting such an act. That said, this would seem to be one of those times...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit agreed.  In this case it was to see why the jquery click was working when initMouseEvent seemed to be failing.